# How do we connect to snowflake using python connector

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```sh
C:\Users\rkumarsah>pip install cx_oracle
Requirement already satisfied: cx_oracle in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (8.0.1)
```

```sh
C:\Users\rkumarsah>pip install snowflake.connector
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017F3AA38130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/snowflake-connector/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017F3A9BEA30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/snowflake-connector/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017F3A9BEFD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/snowflake-connector/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017F3A9BEDF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/snowflake-connector/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000017F3A9BE970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/snowflake-connector/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement snowflake.connector (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for snowflake.connector
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question still misses some content/context. See [here on how to ask properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That being said, consider providing (a) your Python version and (b) are you running it from `venv;pipenv;anaconda;global interpreter`? Also, [here is the snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the correct name when installing the connector. Change your `pip` command to:

```sh
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#step-1-install-the-connector)